# Query based on value selected mysqli

Tags: php, post, mysqli

i am not able to insert values based on option selected.So in case from dropdown Type1 selected below else type 2.In case of type 2 selected gives error/Even tried to keep null value when type 2 selected but only gives error.when type 1 is selected data is inserted.

```
       include_once('db.php');

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $id   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db ,$_POST['id']);
       $Type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db ,$_POST['type']);
       $Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db ,$_POST['date']);
       $Treat = mysqli_real_escape_string($db ,$_POST['treat']);

       if($Type=="1")
       {
             $sql= "INSERT INTO set1(id,type,date,Treat)
                    VALUES('$id','$Type','$Date','$Treat')";

             $query  = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

             if(!$query)
                 echo "You have to fill all values";
             else     
                 echo  "successfully inserted";

       }
       else 
       {
             $sql= "INSERT INTO set1(id, type, date)
                    VALUES('$id', '$Type', '$Date')"; 

             $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

             if(!$query)
                echo mysqli_error();
             else     
                //echo  "successfully inserted";

             echo"<script> alert('Data inserted Successfully'); window.close(); window.opener.location.reload(true);</script>";
       }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Please specify your error too.

Comment: Undefined index: Treat in C:\wamp\www

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes please any comments

Comment: Is your database field allow ```NULL```?

Comment: you can check key before access it from array like ```mysqli_real_escape_string($db ,(isset($_POST['treat'])?$_POST['treat']:''))```

Comment: $_POST['treat'] is probably empty

Comment: in this line `if(Type=="1")`, should have  `$Type`

Comment: it is having $ sign typo

Comment: @Karan Thanks that worked.ofcourse it calls for default value which i assigned '0' instead of null.also would like to know as you asked "s your database field allow NULL? "

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined index: Treat that means

1-`name="treat"` is not defined in your html

2-your html  should be like this

`<input type="text" name="treat">`

and change following

```
if(Type=="1")
       {
```

with

```
if($Type==1)
           {
```

your full html

```
<td class="desc" width="46%" align="right">Treat</td>
  <td class="desc2" width="54%" align="left">
    <span class="desc1"> 
        <select name="treat" style="width:36mm">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT treat FROM add_treat ORDER BY treat " ; 
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['treat']; ?>"></option><?php echo $row['treat']; ?></option>
           <?php }
            ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: please post you html

Answer (score 0):

Right, you need to eval $Type and not Type (which may be a reserved word and if so always evaluates as false). Probably only your second $sql query is being processed.

Once you get the eval statement right then double-check the first $sql string:

```
"INSERT INTO set1(id,type,date,Treat)
                    VALUES('$id','$Type','$Date','$Treat',)"
```

is not a valid SQL statement -- it has an extra comma at the end